# UsbManager RequestPermission Returns Null

Tags: android, xamarin, usb, android-permissions

Am fairly new to Xamarin development, have found some code that gets me to connect to a usb device (a thermal printer in this case).
Am trying to request permissions, but the request appears to be returning null.

```
var matchingDevice = usbManager.DeviceList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value.VendorId == vendorId && item.Value.ProductId == productId);
             if (usbManager.DeviceList.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("No USB device connected");
             if (matchingDevice.Value == null)
                throw new Exception("Device not found, try to configure it in settings.");

             // DeviceList is a dictionary with the port as the key, so pull out the device you want.  I save the port too
             var usbPort = matchingDevice.Key;
             var usbDevice = matchingDevice.Value;

             // Get permission from the user to access the device (otherwise connection later will be null)
             if (!usbManager.HasPermission(usbDevice))
             {
                try
                {
                   //PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Forms.Context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
                   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(MainActivity.Instance, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
                   usbManager.RequestPermission(usbDevice, pi);
                   throw new Exception("Relaunch the application");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   throw new Exception($"{usbDevice.DeviceName} - {ex.Message}");
                }
             }
```

When I run the app, I get the port number, device number and device name, but the popup for permissions says 'Allow  to  access null'
Why would RequestPermission try and attach a device to null? Any help would be massively appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: First of all, First of all check the `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" android:required="false" />`If add it to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.  I recommand you to read this article before you used it. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT thanks for that link, some useful information in there which should hopefully help me.

Comment: Did you try add the attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT would attribute would that be? Apologies, am new to Xamarin, all that outside of my knowledge base at the moment!!

Comment: I write a simple code, you can test it.https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/GetUSBPermission  I do not have these devices. I cannot test it for you.